# Why is my react web app returning a white/blank page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, hosting

I've been trying to host a react web app that was created with create-react-app. I'm using Hostinger. All I get is this white/blank page.

On my local server it works fine, on github pages it works fine.
Currently, I have "homepage" in package.json set up to the right domain. I also tried setting it up to "." as some people suggested to other similar questions.

At first I was getting 2 errors on the console:

1. The stylesheet was not loaded because its MIME type, "text/html" is not "text/css".
2. SyntaxError: expected expression, got "<".

After a lot of tweaks and rebuilds, I still get the white/blank page, but now the console gives me 404 statuses for multiple files. They are:

- static/css/main.0d200d10.chunk.css
- static/js/2.f331c7cc.chunk.js
- static/js/main.0e5eb86e.chunk.js

It also now gives 1 warning for 2 separate files:

- Loading failed for the <script> with source “<url>/static/js/2.f331c7cc.chunk.js”.” and source “<url>/static/js/main.0e5eb86e.chunk.js”.

This is what index.html looks like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>Cachorro Sensível Filmes</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

The website is https://cachorrosensivel.com.br

Any idea is very welcomed.

EDIT: I'm back to the 2 original errors mentioned after re-uploading the .htaccess. If I specify "type=text/jsx" in my script tag and remove "rel=stylesheet" from the link tag, I get no errors, but it's blank still.

I'm testing on Chrome and Firefox, and I've cleared caches.

Comment: Everything comes down to the 404 errors. You haven't deployed the entire application, or if you have, not to the right URLs.

Comment: "`"type=text/jsx"` in my script tag" — This tells the browser the script is written in a language it doesn't understand so it doesn't download it at all. It stops the 404 error but makes the problem worse.

Comment: "remove `"rel=stylesheet"` from the link tag" — This tells the browser that it isn't a stylesheet so it doesn't download … ditto

Comment: "Currently, I have "homepage" in package.json set up to the right domain." — This tells people who have downloaded the NPM package for your React application where the project homepage is. It has nothing to do with where you deploy the website built with that React application.

Comment: I run npm run build. The build folder is created with single files and 3 separate folders (media, css, js). I select each file and upload all to public_html. Whatever I'm missing, I imagine is before run build.

Comment: You're putting media, css and js *directly* in public_html? When the URLs start with /static/ ?

Comment: With the original problems I get 200 status for everything, but content-type is text/html. I have "rel=stylesheet" and don't have "type=text/jsx".

Comment: At first I was extracting the files from each folder because I understood that the folders wouldn't be extracted on their own. Then I decided to try it anyways with the folders, since nothing was working. That didn't work either. I decided to try again now that you mentioned aaaand I guess I missed the static folder... lost a lot of time with this one. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I messed up the upload to the file manager. It goes public_html -> files/static folder -> folders inside static -> files.